# Flutter : Imagepath url is uploading late from firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to display an image from my firebase storage and its path/filename is stored in firestore. But it is not loading

Function to get the file name from firestore:-

```
Future<dynamic> GetUserModel(String? documentId) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(documentId)
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      var data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var filePath = data['profileImageUrl']! as String;
      print(filePath);
      return filePath;
    } else {
      print('Document does not exist on the database');
      return null;
    }
  });
}
```

To get the download link from storage and display:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getUserImagePath(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  snapshot.data!,
                ),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error);
            }
            return Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: (24 / 40) * widget.profileRadius * 2,
            );
          }),
```

Function to get image URL:-

```
Future<String> getUserImagePath() async {
    final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userRef = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    String userEmail = user!.email.toString();
    print(userEmail);
    var fileName = await GetUserModel(userEmail).toString();
    print(fileName);
    String urlPath = 'users/${userEmail}/UserProfile/${fileName}';
    print(urlPath);
    final userProfileUrl = await userRef.child(urlPath).getDownloadURL();
    print(userProfileUrl);
    return userProfileUrl;
  }

Error/warning/information in terimnal-
I/flutter (  717): [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
I/flutter (  717): test@test.com
I/flutter (  717): Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (  717): users/test@test.com/UserProfile/Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
I/flutter (  717): Screenshot_2022-06-08-18-58-49-66_680d03679600f7af0b4c700c6b270fe7.jpg
I/flutter (  717): Screenshot_2022-06-08-18-58-49-66_680d03679600f7af0b4c700c6b270fe7.jpg
E/StorageException(  717): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(  717): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(  717):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(  717): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException(  717): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }
```

you can see at the time file Path(ScreenShot_2022...etc.) is not loaded but came as Instance of 'Future' but after some time it came so can help how to solve this.

[Firebase Storage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZtIZ.png)

Comment: I am asking about why it is coming as 'users/test@test.com/UserProfile/Instance of future<dynamic>' instead of 'users/test@test.com/UserProfile/Screenshot _2022_06-................'

Comment: since i tried it but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to make sure that you are awaiting the future first before calling toString.  What you're doing now is calling toString on the Future before it's awaited.

```
    var fileName = (await GetUserModel(userEmail)).toString();
```

You probably don't even need the call to toString at all if GetUserModel returns a future that yields a string.